# Why is the sky blue?

Tags: visible-light, scattering, atmospheric-science

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the sky change color?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17/why-does-the-sky-change-color)

Basically what the title says. What mechanisms are significant and how do they contribute to make the sky blue. Also when the sky is not blue, like when the sun sets, how does it happen?

Comment: Related to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17/

Comment: Hello Andreas, Please have in mind, to refer to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering) before asking such questions. It's also a duplicate... Be Careful while posting next questions....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of scattering. Blue light scatters more then other colours, because of its high frequency.

For more information read

http://www.sciencemadesimple.com/sky_blue.html

Comment: It's better to avoid answering duplicated questions... :-)

Comment: I did not notice

Answer (score 1):

Sunset & Sunrise sky is reddish coz red light with longer wavelength tend to travel longer in atmosphere.

And when Sun is up in the sky Blue light is reflected mostly by the gases in atmosphere. Visible lights with longer wavelengths pass right through(actually, around).

Comment: Hello Sparkot, Your answers are good. But, it won't be noticed 'cause it's already in this site.

Comment: Even still, the lack of information might confuse some. The red light is seen because scattering is high and red light isn't as scattered because it has a high wavelength ($~700\text{ nm}$) and Rayleigh says that scattering is inversely proportional to the 4th power of the wavelength.