# How can the sky be blue and transparent at the same time, from below and above?

Tags: visible-light, scattering, earth, vision

The **sky is blue, when looking from below**. That's based on scattering, no problem with that: [Why is the sky blue?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/40875/42975)

But it is also **colorless transparent from above**. No problem with that either, we look straight to the ground, there is only air in between.

**So it has a color, and no color, at the same time. That is surprising!**

Independent of color, that it is colored from only one side is strange. It is not opake blue from below, as we can see the sun.

That reminds of a half transparent mirror. It's not the same, as a mirror creates reflection, not scattering.
The blue color is created by scattering. Shouldn't scattering go to all directions?

**How can the sky have two colors at the same time?**

Comment: It is not transparent from only one side, you can see stuff beyond atmosphere, e.g. (a part from the sun, obviously) the moon, some planets, comets etc

Comment: And it's obviously (mostly) transparent at night

Comment: @fqq For a strict definition of obvious, it's not so obvious. But let's assume the question implies it's night.

Comment: Please do not post answers in the comments. If you know the answer to the question, please post it as a proper answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

From below you are looking up at the atmosphere with a black background beyond it.
From above the background is reflecting significant amounts of light and so you see the background.

This picture from a satellite shows the background visible but getting less so as the light passes through more and more atmosphere towards the rim.

[image]

Here is the effect at night (for most of Earth) with the rim showing the scattering of blue light from the atmosphere.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Blue (red and other) colors of the sky come from Rayleigh scattering effects: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering . And no: its effects are not equal in all directions!
2. White and grey colors of the clouds come from Mie scattering (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mie_scattering )
3. Remember additive and subtractive color mixing difference. The different colors you see at the sky result from different effects.
4. And last but not least: remember colors are just human perception of (mixed) frequencies.