# Color of sky scattering by sky dust

Tags: visible-light, everyday-life, scattering

> Why does we see sky like  blue in maximum time?

We know violet has less wavelength, so we should see sky like violet.
My assumption is that, violet is not primary color and not sufficient in the spectrum so we see blue because after violet, blue has the shortest wavelength?

**Edit: Because our eyes have sensibility for three primary colors so we may see primary color most but, If a people is blue color blind then what sky color will he see?**

Comment: possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17/

Comment: The first question already has an answer (see michielm's comment), the second question is more a biology (specifically psychology) question..!

Comment: But I think 2nd question is bio-physics related.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the sky not purple?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28895/)