# Scattering of light by gas molecules in Atmosphere, responsible for sky's blue color?

Tags: visible-light, scattering, atmospheric-science

What do we mean when we say gas molecules in air scatter sun light (more blue)?

Do they reflect sunlight? Is **beam** of sunlight falling on one molecule and each rays got reflected into different random angles (specially blue color)?

Or a **ray** hit on a molecule  got reflected in one direction?

What **actually** is happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the sky change color? Why is the sky blue during the day, red during sunrise/set and black during the night?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17/)

Answer (score 1):

In scattering of light sunlight is absorbed and re-emitted by air molecules
$$I\propto\frac{1}{\lambda^4}.$$ Since blue light has lower wavelength in the visible range it scatters the most.
The actual phenomenon is caused due to electric polarization of gases. The electric field in light causes the molecules to vibrate at the same frequency of light. This causes the formation of radiating dipoles. These dipoles emits radiations which we see as scattered light.